# Limit of expectation of L2 norm unbounded implies function ill defined

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a random process
$A(t,x) := \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} A^N(t,x)$ where $ x \in (0,1)$ and $t \geq 0$ and given that 
\begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^1 A^N(t,x)^2 dx \right] = tN \end{equation}
show that $A(t,x)$ is not well defined as a process taking values in $L^2(0,1)$ for each value of $t$ almost surely.

Now, I want to argue that taking the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ we can clearly see that the RHS of our expectation result, i.e. the expectation of the $L^2$ norm, diverges and the process is no longer square integrable almost surely but I'm uncomfortable with this for a number of reasons. Firstly, I'm not sure I'm confident in saying that an expectation of a norm diverging implies that the norm is divergent for each $t$ almost surely, couldn't it just be that it is divergent for some subset of times $t$ and for all other times it is bounded but this subset is enough to make the expectation unbounded? Secondly, I'm slightly uncomfortable even making the manipulation

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^1 A(t,x) \right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1 \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} A^N(t,x)^2 dx \right] \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1 A^N(t,x)^2 dx\right] \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} tN
\end{align}

since I'm not sure it is even valid to extract the limit from the expectation as such.

For reference this is in the context of brownian motion if that helps. If anyone has any thoughts they would be much appreciated!